# How is one supposed to practically use the Access Control features in the Realm Mobile Platform?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I don't see an easy way to grant permissions to another user. It seems to be quite convoluted at the moment, and I wonder if I'm missing something obvious.

Say I want to invite another user to share a Realm. First I would have to ask the other user for their identification, then I would create the permission object, and then finally I would give the other user the address of my realm.

It would be great if I could share some sort of permission token via text message and let the new user register themselves. I suppose I could do that if I created another "User" which represented the shared group, and merely share this abstract user's credentials. It feels a bit hacky that way, but it seems easier to do.

I was hoping the [demo application of the shared drawing environment](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/objc/Draw) would hold a clue, but after looking at the source code, it turns out both devices are logged in as the same user.

Am I missing something? Given the demo *Draw* application, how would one user practically invite a second user to join in their shared drawing environment? It seems like there would have to be a whole set of convoluted permissions and url/identification sharing handshakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking the question! Today, you will need to create a shared Realm that all users would input their user IDs into and have access to. This way any user can look up an ID and share access to another Realm.

We realize the limitations and are working on offering a number of improvements. The first is pretty close to what you describe, called a `PermissionOffer` object where you can inform the Realm Object Server you want to grant access to another user for a given Realm(s). The server will then provide a token you can share via any means with the other user. That user can then use the token to create a `PermissionOfferResponse` object and accept the access grant. This is coming soon, so stay tuned!

Later, we plan to offer a way to lookup user IDs so you don't have to replicate all of them in a shared Realm ([see this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/67#issuecomment-267535014)).

Comment: The `PermissionOffer` API sounds like exactly what I want. I'll try things the other way for now. Thanks for the quick response! Realm is absolutely incredible so far. I hope my question didn't sound too demanding. I just wanted to be as clear as possible, so I resisted the urge to couch it in a bunch of compliments ;D

Comment: No problem at all! Good to know we are on the right track with upcoming features. Look out in the coming weeks.

Comment: @KitLangton, if we have a shared realm for all users, doesn't this mean that every single user will have a local copy of that realm? And how this would work if we have 1000000 users and up? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes that means there is 1 Realm managed by the Realm Object Server and the X clients would have a local copy. The Realm Object Server can support >10k or more concurrent connections depending on how much data is being transferred (we have tested into hundreds of thousands, it just depends on workload and server specs).

Comment: Downloading the whole userbase doesn't seem quite right to me. If the realm file is large this means when a user first starts app, it will have to download this large file. Are there any other options? For example querying a server realm without downloading it?

Comment: Right now we don't support partial sync of a Realm file. You can definitely break up a dataset into multiple Realms and sync each part as needed. For example, a couple companies are using Realm to push out updates to a shared mapping dataset to clients. In this case, they can optimize it by breaking it up into "region" Realms, then use the user's current location to sync the region they are in vs. the entire dataset.